# What is this adapter and what can I replace it with for simpler operation?

Tags: power, adapter

My church plant uses the D3540 pager - https://www.microframecorp.com/d3540-4-digit-wireless-visual-pager-display

We have to setup and tear down the pager system every week. We have to manually wire the 2-wire power connector into the green connector - shown below and at the link above - and it's a finicky/difficult process. The wire is always loose, and wiring is stressful for some of our setup team.

Is there some plug-in adapter replacement I can use to make this better? I'd love to convert it to just use a standard A/C adapter, but I'll take any improvements.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This is a perfectly ordinary terminal block, nothing special about it. You could replace it with some kind of actual two-part connector, or just something that doesn't require a screwdriver to properly grip the wires.

Comment: Drill a hole in the end of the cabinet, add a panel-mount power jack socket, solder a pair of wires to the terminals and wire those back to the green terminals and then plug in a suitable PSU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are capable of splicing coax and terminating the pigtails to the screw terminals reliably with heatshrink, wire and solder , then this can work for you. Or find a tech who can make them for you, or ask Digikey to make the pigtails.

[image]  Male-Female extension cable AWG 18
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tensility-international-corp/CA-2216/CP-2216-ND/1129479

The heatshink is intended as the braid insulation-cut-edge strain-relief.

### Plan B

tin-lead Solder the wire ends with only enough solder to coat all the wires and allow heat to wick it up just inside the insulation.

For frequent teardowns, the frayed wires should no more be a problem.

Comment: Can you help me understand what this is? It's a male/female adapter, but what do I do with it? Cut it in half and wire the male end to the board and the female end to the power supply?

Comment: yes thats it....